# Print to stdout process ids that were killed

Tags: linux, kill, jobs

Using the `kill` command, is there a way to print to `stdout` the process ids of the background processes being killed?
After searching via Google, there seems to be (on some Unix or Linux) a `--verbose` option but it does not seem to be available on Ubuntu 20.x or CentOS 7.x.

If this cannot be done with just the `kill` command, can it be done in some other fashion via the CLI (e.g. with `kill` and some other commands)?

Here is an example of the commands I am using to kill background processes:

```
kill $(jobs -p)
```

When running this example, I would like to see the process ids that are being killed, if possible.

This is what I found on the internet:

```
To enable verbose logging pass the --verbose flag to the kill command. 
Note that this is not supported by all shell built-ins so may not be available on your system.
    
    kill --verbose 17146
    sending signal 15 to pid 17146
```

More info:

```
/usr/bin/kill --verbose 8411
Usage:
 kill [options] <pid|name> [...]
Options:
 -a, --all              do not restrict the name-to-pid conversion to processes
                        with the same uid as the present process
 -s, --signal <sig>     send specified signal
 -q, --queue <sig>      use sigqueue(2) rather than kill(2)
 -p, --pid              print pids without signaling them
 -l, --list [=<signal>] list signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list signal names and numbers
 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit
For more details see kill(1).
```

So, on my system, it is apparently not available.  Any suggestions on a workaround or equivalent solution?

Solution: `jobs -p | xargs -t kill`

Comment: Did you try the -verbose Option even if the man page does not show it?

Comment: Yes.  I got an error.  Seems the `kill` command parses the `--verbose` option and thinks it is a signal, which of course it is not.

Comment: please provide `type -a kill` and `/usr/bin/kill --version`.

Comment: type -a kill
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /usr/bin/kill

Comment: /usr/bin/kill --version
kill from util-linux 2.23.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill` is a shell built-in

```
   $ type -a kill

    kill is a shell builtin
    kill is /usr/bin/kill
```

if you want to use `--verbose` you need to call `kill` command

```
   $ /usr/bin/kill --verbose 4935

    sending signal 15 to pid 4935
```

I checked in SUSE 12 (util-linux 2.33.2) and Centos 8 (util-linux 2.32.1),
`verbose` is a valid option. Maybe your distro has compiled `kill` with different flags. As a workaround you can run with `-p` for logging purpose which only `prints the pids`.

```
/usr/bin/kill --help

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid>|<name>...

Forcibly terminate a process.

Options:
 -a, --all              do not restrict the name-to-pid conversion to processes
                          with the same uid as the present process
 -s, --signal <signal>  send this <signal> instead of SIGTERM
 -q, --queue <value>    use sigqueue(2), not kill(2), and pass <value> as data
 -p, --pid              print pids without signaling them
 -l, --list[=<signal>]  list signal names, or convert a signal number to a name
 -L, --table            list signal names and numbers
     --verbose          print pids that will be signaled

 -h, --help             display this help
 -V, --version          display version
```

Comment: see More Info in my OP.  Just added because I couldn't out it in a comment.

Comment: @tale852150I updated the answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example with the kill -p option and using the jobs command as I mentioned in the OP, please?

Comment: @tale852150 you can do many things for this case, like `jobs -p; kill $(jobs -p)`. this will run `jobs -p` first and prints the PIDs and then kills them. you can do it in 1 command with `jobs -p | xargs -t kill`. no need for `--verbose` or `-p` of `kill` command

Comment: I like the xargs solution...completely forgot about that approach.

Comment: The xargs solution will do fine.  Pleased include that in your answer so I can accept it.